# JPA and Hiberate - ID Generation Seq # with current Date (20170809)

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I know in hibernate we can use sequence strategy to generate Unique ID. However,

I want to know that is there any way to generate Unique ID as Sequence + Current Date

Example,

1(seq curr val) is the sequence no and current Date is 20170809. Assume sequence is marked for cycle max is 9999

so Id should generate sequence as 20170809-0001

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can implement your own generator.
To do that you  have to extend the class `org.hibernate.id.SequenceGenerator.
In that class you have to override the method`generate`, and make it return the desired value.
then you specify your class in the strategy of the generator. Mapping should looks like that

```
<id name="id" type="string" column="my_id">
    <generator class="org.mycomp.mygenerator">
            <param name="table">myseq</param>

    </generator>
```

hope it help
r

Comment: so, in that custom class,  will i have make DB calls to get seq and append current date?

Comment: extending the SequenceGenerator you can make it call to the super of method generate  wich give you a BigInteger.